# Azure Metrics Graphs showing different results depending on style

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

I am building some SQL dashboards in Azure using the standard metrics. Specifically, I'm charting DTU Usage against DTU Limits. I'm plotting max values for each one.

With the "Line Chart" style, I get this:
[Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjgsC.png)

Which suggests that I'm using, at most, about half mt DTU limit.

However, if I switch the style to "Bar Chart" I get this: [Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtNu2.png)

Which suggests that I'm going over my DTU limit almost every day.

So now, I'm wondering which interpretation is correct? My gut tells me that the line chart is right and I'm just seeing a "stacking bar chart" that is summing both values rather than the more traditional bar chart that I'm accustomed to. I can't find any resources in the Azure documentation that speak to this. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi ,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the "Bar chart", as you said, the value of Y-axis range is the sum of the two metrics or a little higher, these metrics share one Y-axis .

It looks like that you're going over your DTU limit almost every day, because Azure mix the two metrics value in one bar.

For example in "Bar chart", when we want to see the DTU limit max, we should move the mouse to the "**DTU limit(max)**"  in the lower left corner:

[image]

"**DTU used(max)**":
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Over the last few years I have seen many complaints about the DTU graph as [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d6497224-f46f-41f4-9180-1e307acab08a/dtu-graph-not-working-right?forum=ssdsgetstarted) one. The graph is sometimes inconsistent as shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e1d799c-0734-4d58-b27e-c521be93422a/azure-database-graph-scale?forum=ssdsgetstarted).

Please run the following query to verify resource consumption over the last 7 days. You may find the result of the query more accurate than the DTU graph.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
WHERE database_name = 'AdventureWorksLT' AND           
start_time > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```